# CSS3 select an ID name for check boxes apply changes

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors

I'm on a web app build and I encounter some trouble to select multiple ID. I would like to use theses IDs to apply movement on a wrapper, but the selector don't make the job.

There is the unuseful code:

```
div[id*="article_"]:checked ~ .article_wrapper {moving wrapper code}
```

The name selector need to be effective with "`.article_001`" to "`.article_999`", so I don't want to have a huge copy/paste on my stylesheet.

If someone know how to do it perfectly and of course I don't want to use something else to CSS selectors.

Comment: What do you mean by checked, because div don't have checked state? You may wanted input there?

Comment: Your selector seems confused. Your selector refers to IDs but then you refer to class selectors, and as @Hiszpan pointed out you're testing a :checked pseudo on a div...

Comment: It's a simple toggle trick, check this example to see my base. Maybe a trick based itself on a weird complex reaction…
https://codepen.io/elgreg/pen/rGgfF